# Is it possible to remove individual values from an file input multiple element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to remove or somehow nullify a single value in a single input for multiple files. Let's say we have four values...

```
<input id="input" multiple="multiple" type="file" />
input = document.getElementById('input');
// So our four files are:
input.files[0];
input.files[1];
input.files[2];
input.files[3];
```

if I wanted to remove [1] from the array without disrupting the others, can I do it? I've tried splicing, setting the value to NULL, changing the name etc. None of this stuff seems to work (while the element remains readonly = false) Jquery's remove function removes the entire element so that doesn't work.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove one specific selected file from input file control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19060378/how-to-remove-one-specific-selected-file-from-input-file-control)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It’s [readonly](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/#dfn-filelist).

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious to why splice does not work. Normally it's very easy to do this:

```
var list = [4,5,6];
list.splice(1,1);
console.log(list); // [4,6]
```

So if this doesn't work, I'd like to know what the results are.

**Edit**

Btw, you need to use:

```
var input = document.getElementById('input');
```

You have to declare your variables with 'var'.

Comment: It doesn't work because (a) the `files` property (in the browsers that even support it) is a FileList collection and not an Array, so, like other DOM types such as NodeList, it doesn't have a `splice` method. And (b), as jleedev posted, FileList is read-only. Deliberately so, to try to keep interaction with the highly security-sensitive file upload field to a minimum.

Comment: Also @Luwe: one does not have to declare her variables with `var`. It's good practice and they end up in the global scope if one does not, but one doesn't **have** to.

Comment: Here's your results
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<FileList> has no method 'splice' (From chrome)