# Is there a way to remove a attached file in file input (multi select)

Tags: javascript, file, file-upload

I have a file input like

```
 <input type="file" value="" name="upload[]" multiple>
```

Example: When i select 3 file from my computer. Is there a way to remove a special file of 3 file by click a button without browse again? IS that possible?

[image] to [image]

**Edit**
Here is my code

**http://jsfiddle.net/KzeT6/**

Comment: Already asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099573/is-it-possible-to-remove-individual-values-from-an-file-input-multiple-element

Comment: @mguimard I just read the best answer in that question but i don't understand :(. Please see my edit (add code)

Comment: You cannot directly change the input file list. You can however use javascript libraries to handle this for you, here are some demos ... http://blog.insicdesigns.com/2010/02/10-best-ajax-file-uploader-for-your-web-application/