# input type=file multiple, delete items

Tags: javascript, html

**html:**

```
<input accept="image/*" class="" id="my_pics" multiple="multiple" name="pics" required="true" type="file" />
```

**js:**

```
var files = document.getElementById('my_pics').files;
files.splice(1,2)
//TypeError: Object #<FileList> has no method 'splice'
delete files.item(2)
// true, but nothing happens with "2"
delete files[2]
// false, result is the same
```

I have a form with multiple file, I need to upload on server only limited number of images (for example, 5) in **one input**, but my code doesnt work.

How to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: just use files[0-4] in your uploader part, you can't reliably change the files collection itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove one specific selected file from input file control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19060378/how-to-remove-one-specific-selected-file-from-input-file-control)

Answer (score 5):

You can't delete that because it's a `File` object pointed to in the `FileList` object, hence the error above. However, you can iterate over the [`FileList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) and only push the items that you want onto an array, which you can then modify:

```
var files = document.getElementById('my_pics').files;
var newList = [];

for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
{
    if(i !== 2)
    {
        newList.push(files.item(i));
    }
}
```

As you can see from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742623/deleting-objects-in-javascript#742666), you can't `delete` the actual object. Only the reference to the object can be deleted. So, even if it worked for the `FileList` object, which it doesn't, it would only set [that element equal to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500606/javascript-array-delete-elements#500617) `undefined`.