# JavaScript delete File from FileList to be uploaded

Tags: javascript, file, file-upload, input, filereader

There is the code https://jsfiddle.net/bfzmm1hc/1 Everything looks fine but I want to delete some of the files from the set.

I have already found these:

- [How to remove one specific selected file from input file control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19060378/how-to-remove-one-specific-selected-file-from-input-file-control)
- [input type=file multiple, delete items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19666064/input-type-file-multiple-delete-items)

I know that `FileList` object is readonly, so I can just copy the files to a new array. But what should I do with this new array of `File` objects? I can't assign it to the `files` property...

Comment: What do you intend to do with the updated `input`, upload the files?

Comment: Yeah, i want to be able to upload edited array of files

Comment: Are you wanting to upload the ones that _are_ images, or the ones that _aren't_ images? Also, did you want to limit to the first four files or did you mean to process all of them?

Comment: No matter is it file or not. I choose 4 images, for example. Then i want just delete the second one and upload 3 images left + some other form field. But I cant just delete the file from FileList...

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I hope you find my answer useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you cannot edit the Read Only [`input.files`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) attribute, you must upload a form [using `XMLHttpRequest` and send a `FormData` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Using_FormData_objects). I will also show you how to use [`URL.createObjectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) to more easily get a URI from the `File` object:

```js
var SomeCl = {
  count: 0,
  init: function() {
    $('#images').change(this.onInputChange);
  },
  onInputChange: function() {
    // reset preview
    $('.container').empty();
    // reset count
    SomeCl.count = 0;
    // process files
    SomeCl.processFiles(this.files, function(files) {
      // filtered files
      console.log(files);

      // uncomment this line to upload the filtered files
      SomeCl.upload('url', 'POST', $('#upload').get(0), files, 'images[]');
    });
  },
  processFiles: function(files, callback) {
    // your filter logic goes here, this is just example

    // filtered files
    var upload = [];

    // limit to first 4 image files
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(files, function(file) {
      if (file.type.slice(0, 5) === 'image' && upload.length < 4) {
        // add file to filter
        upload.push(file);
        // increment count
        SomeCl.count++;
        // show preview
        SomeCl.preview(file);
      }
    });

    callback(upload);
  },
  upload: function(method, url, form, files, filename) {
    // create a FormData object from the form
    var fd = new FormData(form);
    // delete the files in the <form> from the FormData
    fd.delete(filename);
    // add the filtered files instead
    fd.append(filename, files);

    // demonstrate that the entire form has been attached
    for (var key of fd.keys()) {
      console.log(key, fd.getAll(key));
    }

    // use xhr request
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
    xhr.addEventListener('progress', function(e) {
      console.log('lengthComputable', e.lengthComputable);
      console.log(e.loaded + '/' + e.total);
    });
    xhr.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
      console.log('uploaded');
    });
    xhr.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
      console.log('this is just a demo');
    });
    xhr.send(fd);
  },
  preview: function(file) {
    // create a temporary URI from the File
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    // append a preview
    $('.container').append($('<img/>').attr('src', url));
  }
};

SomeCl.init();
```

```css
.container img {
  max-width: 250px;
  max-height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="upload">
  <input name="other" type="hidden" value="something else">
  <input name="images[]" id="images" multiple="multiple" type="file">
  <div class="container"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Wow, looks great, thanks a lot, ill take a look, So there is no way to make it without ajax?

Comment: @user1128677 Unfortunately, there is not. Your other alternative is to provide custom validation to the form so that the user only selects files that should be uploaded.

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround. This will not require AJAX for the request at all and the form can be sent to the server. Basically you could create an `hidden` or `text` input and set it's `value` attribute to the base64 string created after processing the file selected.

```
<input type=hidden value=${base64string} />
```

You will probably consider the idea to create multiple input file instead of input `text` or `hidden`. This will not work as we can't assign a value to it.

This method will include the input file in the data sent to the database and to ignore the input file you could:

- in the back-end don't consider the field;
- you can set the `disabled` attribute to the input file before serialising the form;
- remove the DOM element before sending data.

When you want to delete a file just get the index of the element and remove the input element (text or hidden) from the DOM.

**Requirements:**

- You need to write the logic to convert files in base64 and store all files inside an array whenever the input file trigger the `change` event.

**Pros:**

- This will basically give you **a lot** of control and you can filter, comparing files, check for file size, MIME type, and so on..