# How can delete one object from input type=file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have input type=file for upload file. When I choose 2-3 files, I have list of file. How can I delete only one object which I choose?

```
<input type="file"  data-ng-click="initFiles2()" data-rule-required="true" id="file"  name="file[]"   multiple data-ng-model="file" />
```

I tried like other object from list I delete but in this case is not working.

I tried something like this but not working ...

```
var index = -1;     
    for( var i = 0; i < file.files.length; i++ ) {
        if( file.files[i].name === name ) {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    file.files.splice( index, 1 );
```

'name' is name of the file

Comment: you can dupe inp.files to an array and censor it to your liking...

Comment: You are right, I will do that ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove one specific selected file from input file control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19060378/how-to-remove-one-specific-selected-file-from-input-file-control)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. The *user* can, but you can't. There are no methods on [`FileList`](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-filelist) that allow you to modify it.

Comment: If the user selects 10 files and displayed his list of files, whether this means that there is no possibility that over some functions give him the ability to delete a one file?  Must all reset if one file wrongly chosen?