# dynamically delete the attachment?

Tags: javascript

I have a form that upload a file..

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="" action="" method="POST">
<input type="file" name="file[]" id="files" multiple />
<div id="selectedFiles"></div>
<form>
```

And a javascript function to display the name and size.

```
<script>
    var selDiv = "";

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);

    function init() {
        document.querySelector('#files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
        selDiv = document.querySelector("#selectedFiles");
    }

    function handleFileSelect(e) {

        if(!e.target.files) return;

        selDiv.innerHTML = "";


        var files = e.target.files;
        for(var i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
            var f = files[i];

            selDiv.innerHTML += "<span class='attach'>" + f.name + " <" + f.size + " bytes>" + "</span>";

        }

    }
    </script>
```

**is their anyone know how to make a delete function on the attachment??**

example:

[image]

the image shows the uploaded file.. and the red "x" is the delete...
can anyone please help me with this? using javascript..

Comment: To delete the file on the server you would need some server-side script, i.e. php. The best you could do with javascript is to remove it from the list.

Comment: @Tro - sir, how it could be removed from the list using javascript??

Comment: Take a look at jQuery (https://jquery.com/), plenty of ways to remove an element from the page.

Comment: @Tro yes, but jQuery isn't going to delete it from the list of files scheduled to be upldated by the file upload input.

Comment: Basically you can not remove it from the file list. There are work arounds using File APi reading file, and uploading it differently...

Comment: Wait, you want that when you click on the X, it'd display `1 file selected`?

Comment: @klenium - yes sir.... then it display only the 1 file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove one specific selected file from input file control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19060378/how-to-remove-one-specific-selected-file-from-input-file-control)

Comment: You should hide the file input, then you don't have to bother with the defuault text, the user won't see the "1-2 files selected". Add a custom `<button>`, list the selected files under it that you can remove, and use AJAX to send the files that the user didn't remove.

Comment: @klenium - can you please refer with samole code sir...

Answer (score 1):

See comments below.

```
<form action="some.php" method="post" id="form">
    <input type="file" id="file" multiple style="display: none;" />
    <button type="button" id="button">Select files</button>
    <div id="selectedFiles"></div>
    <button type="submit" id="submit">Upload</button>
<form>
```

```
var selDiv = document.querySelector("#selectedFiles");
document.querySelector("#button").addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.querySelector("#file").click();
}, false);
document.querySelector("#file").addEventListener("change", function() {
    var files = this.files;
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; ++i) {
        var file = files[i],
            span = document.createElement("span");
        span.className = "attach";
        span.innerHTML = file.name+" <"+file.size+" bytes>";
        span.file = file;
        var remove = document.createElement("span");
        remove.innerHTML = "Remove";
        span.appendChild(remove);
        selDiv.appendChild(span);
        remove.addEventListener("click", function() {
            this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
        }, false);
    }
}, false);
document.querySelector("#form").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    var files = selDiv.querySelectorAll("span.attach"),
        data = new FormData(),
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; ++i) {
        data.append("file[]", files[i].file);
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            selDiv.innerHTML = "Uploading completed!";
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "upload.php", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send(data);
    return false;
}, false);
```

Comment: @Bee Edited my answer.