# Multiple file upload - with 'remove file' link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a form where I can have multiple file upload sections, where the user can upload multiple files.

That part, is reasonably straight forward. My problem comes from allowing the user to 'remove' a file from the upload list, before it's uploaded.

I've created a fiddle to illustrate
http://jsfiddle.net/alexjamesbrown/o62srbew/

I've got a simple row, that holds the `<input type="file"`

```
<div class="row files" id="files1">
    <h2>Files 1</h2>
    <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
        Browse  <input type="file" name="files1" multiple />
    </span>
    <br />
    <ul class="fileList"></ul>
</div>
```

then, so far, I've created a jquery plugin so it's re-usable:

```
$.fn.fileUploader = function (filesToUpload) {
    this.closest(".files").change(function (evt) {

        for (var i = 0; i < evt.target.files.length; i++) {
            filesToUpload.push(evt.target.files[i]);
        };
        var output = [];

        for (var i = 0, f; f = evt.target.files[i]; i++) {
            var removeLink = "<a href=\"#\" data-fileid=\"" + i + "\">Remove</a>";

            output.push("<li><strong>", escape(f.name), "</strong> - ",
                f.size, " bytes. &nbsp; &nbsp; ", removeLink, "</li> ");
        }

        $(this).children(".fileList")
            .append(output.join(""));
    });
};
```

I'm then initialising my very basic plugin like this:

```
var filesToUpload = [];

$("#files1").fileUploader(filesToUpload);
$("#files2").fileUploader(filesToUpload);

$("#uploadBtn").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove one specific selected file from input file control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19060378/how-to-remove-one-specific-selected-file-from-input-file-control)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As in this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/89k4kuvd/1/), I've added a class name `.removeFile` to the dynamically generated `remove` link; then use this class as a selector to pick up the one which is clicked and remove the parent `li`.

***Updated:***

**JS:**

```
// add .removeFile class to the li's element to pick them by this selector
var removeLink = "<a class=\"removeFile\" href=\"#\" data-fileid=\"" + i + "\">Remove</a>";

        output.push("<li><strong>", escape(f.name), "</strong> - ",
            f.size, " bytes. &nbsp; &nbsp; ", removeLink, "</li> ");
    }

    $(this).children(".fileList")
        .append(output.join(""));
    });
};

var filesToUpload = [];

$(document).on("click",".removeFile", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var fileName = $(this).parent().children("strong").text();

     // loop through the files array and check if the name of that file matches FileName
    // and get the index of the match
    for(i = 0; i < filesToUpload.length; ++ i){
        if(filesToUpload[i].name == fileName){
            //console.log("match at: " + i);
            // remove the one element at the index where we get a match
            filesToUpload.splice(i, 1);
        }   
    }

    //console.log(filesToUpload);
    // remove the <li> element of the removed file from the page DOM
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

You can un-comment the console.log() statements to see the result

Comment: this removes the `<li>` tag but doesn't actually do anything to the underlying `input` field - the file is still here, and is still uploaded....

Comment: @Alex, sorry man I thought the problem was with picking the one that should be removed I apologize, I've updated the code now and it is works well, please check it and hopefully this will work for you

Comment: Thank you! Your solution helped me implement a user-required feature.