# Bootstrap Twitter input type file how to clear the file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm implementing option for the user in the form where they can select one of allowed files and upload. This feature interface is build in Bootstrap 3 and I found one of the blogs that helped me style the interface. However, I'm wondering if there is a good option to clear/remove selected file? In case if user decided not to upload the file how they can remove it? I would need like X delete button on the very right side. Also file has to be remove with JavaScript I guess. If anyone knows the way to achieve this please let me know. Here is my code example:

```js
$("#frm_file").on("change", uploadFile);
function uploadFile() {
    var ftype = $(this).get(0).files[0].type,
        fname = $(this).get(0).files[0].name,
        fextension = fname.split('.').pop(), // Another way to get file extension: fname.substring(fname.lastIndexOf('.')+1);
        validExtensions = ["jpg","jpeg","png","gif","doc","docx","xls","xlsx","txt","pdf"];
        console.log(fname);
    $("#frm_filename").val(fname);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="file"><span class="label label-default">File:</span></label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <label class="input-group-btn">
                                                    <span class="btn btn-primary">
                                                        Browse&hellip; <input type="file" name="frm_file" id="frm_file" style="display: none;">
                                                    </span>
                                                </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="frm_filename" id="frm_filename" readonly>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very basic example using the bootstrap button on the right hand side. This is practically taken from the bootstrap 3.7 website.   https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#forms

```
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputGroupSuccess2" aria-describedby="inputGroupSuccess2Status">
  </div>
  <span id="clear" class="input-group-addon">X</span>
</div>

<script>
    Document.getElementById("clear").addEventListener("click", clearInput);

    Function clearInput(){
        Document.getElementById("clear").Value = "";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
document.getElementById('frm_file').value = "";
```

If not, try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19060378/how-to-remove-one-specific-selected-file-from-input-file-control/19236295#19236295) answer.

Answer (score -1):

In case you're banging your head against a brick wall like I've been, if you're using the [`.custom-file-input` option from Bootstrap 4.x](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/forms/#file-browser), none of the many and varied ways of clearing your file input will work. As the docs describe, this class causes Bootstrap to "hide the default file `<input>` via opacity and instead style the `<label>`". So to clear it, this is what I did:

Given (from the Bootstrap docs):

```
<div class="custom-file">
  <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile">
  <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose file</label>
</div>
```

Use:

```
var $input = $('#customFile')
$input.val(null);
$input.next('label').text('Choose file');
```