# Remove Filelist object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to delete or remove an object from Filelist of `<input type="file"multiple/>` in Javascript or JQuery but could not remove or delete the object.

I was trying to delete with an operator like `delete $(input[type="file"]).files[0];` but is not working either.

Comment: `delete` operator is not meant for that purpose, you should use `$('input[type="file"]').first().remove()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove one specific selected file from input file control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19060378/how-to-remove-one-specific-selected-file-from-input-file-control)

Comment: Are you trying to remove only a single file in this FileList or all of them?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```js
let deleteButton =  document.getElementById("deleteFiles");
deleteButton.onclick  = function () {
     let element = document.getElementById("filesInput");
     console.log("Files: ");
     console.log(element.files);
     element.value = '';
     console.log("Files after removal: ");
     console.log(element.files);
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="filesInput">
<button id="deleteFiles">delete file</button>
```

This is implemented on vanillaJavascript but you can use Jquery to help you throw the implementation.