# How to remove certain file from multiple input type="file"?

Tags: javascript

I've got an issue with my uploads,
I'm using [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) with `readAsDataURL()` method, when user select its images then he can preview files.
Also I have a button which has classname `"del-first"`, when user click on it first image should be deleted from preview and also from input value. That's my problem.

**So I have an input:**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="myFiles" name="myFiles[]" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" multiple />
    <div class="preview-wrapper">
        <button class="del-first"></button>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
</form>
```

**My Javscript:**

```
const fileInput = document.getElementById("myFiles");

function previewFiles() {

  var preview = document.querySelector('.preview-wrapper');
  var files   = fileInput.files;

  function readAndPreview(file) {

    // Make sure `file.name` matches our extensions criteria
    if ( /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i.test(file.name) ) {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.addEventListener("load", function() {
        var conta = document.createElement('div');
        conta.className = "preview-image";

        var image = new Image();
        image.height = 100;
        image.title = file.name;
        image.src = this.result;

        conta.appendChild( image );
        preview.appendChild( conta );
      }, false);

      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

  }

  if (files) {
    [].forEach.call(files, readAndPreview);
  }

  var newFileList = Array.from(event.target.files);
  console.log(newFileList);

  var imgRemove = document.querySelector('.del-first');

  imgRemove.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    newFileList.splice(0,1);
    console.log(newFileList);
  })

}

fileInput.addEventListener("change", previewFiles);
```

As you can see in the end of the script I used array.from for my files:

```
var newFileList = Array.from(event.target.files);
```

then I added listener, when user click button first object should be deleted:

```
var imgRemove = document.querySelector('.del-first');
        
imgRemove.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   newFileList.splice(0,1);
   console.log(newFileList);
})
```

So in my console.log I'm getting that it has been deleted, but now I need somehow push my `newFileList` to my input, so when user click `submit` I get on my server valid files. But I don't know how to make it?

Comment: The `.files` property on the `<input>` element is read-only. Only the browser user can set the list of files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove one specific selected file from input file control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19060378/how-to-remove-one-specific-selected-file-from-input-file-control)

Comment: @HereticMonkey Unfortunately, no.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show how you've applied the answers to that question to your situation and found them lacking. The questions are almost identical in what they are asking.

Comment: @HereticMonkey That solution only works if you're NOT uploading the files from Form Submit, that's for sure. Then the answer isn't correct, he used foreach not correct, because files are objects. His code isn't good, you should understand this. It doesn't solve what I'm asking for.

Comment: There is another answer to the question. One that does not require using ajax to upload the data. The accepted answer is only the answer that helped one person the most.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Second one is using base64 is the hardest way to get simple image to your server, you should write new logic on your server side to filter and decode files that you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my understanding, I don't think you could remove the file from your file list. The file's data in `files` is read-only, so I recommend you use multiple `<input type="file">` for adding file instead of `<input type="file" multiple>`, so that you can easily remove the specific file with the simple remove button (clear the value of the `file` input). It may be inconvenient for the user, but it works in your case I think.

========Update

Instead of using `<input type="file" multiple>`. You can use the alternative way like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/kh0a9fb7/). You can take a look of this

Hope it would help. Please correct me if I were wrong

Comment: inserted of removing files try validating the file you want .Please correct me if I were wrong

Comment: Sorry, so I recommend you use multiple <input type="file"> for adding file instead of <input type="files" - sorry, but I can't understand this line, I'm using multiple input type file. What do you mean?

Comment: @AkForDev I will update my answer for more clearance

Comment: @VivianMascarenhas Sorry but what do you mean about that. Can you please clarify for me about that?

Comment: @AkForDev I've updated my answer, please take a look

Comment: Now I understand what you mean, sorry, but it's not elegant and clear for user. A lot of people want to upload for example 10 pictures, for sure, for them it will be not comfortable.

Comment: If you want another option, you can take a look at this old post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19060378/how-to-remove-one-specific-selected-file-from-input-file-control?noredirect=1&lq=1 . Hope it would help you

Comment: Under my question you can see in comments discussion about this link. Thanks anyway!