Function to select multiple images, preview them, and remove individual image if user doesnt want to include it
I'm using ASP.NET. Here in this razor page (cshtml) I'm trying to create a function where user can select multiple images, preview them, along with a remove button for each individual image. Just like how we can add photos and remove one by one on Facebook.
Right now I have this html and a javascript code. The problem is, when I select 2 images A and B, I remove image A and then submit the form, image B is gone too. Which means the remove button resets the entire file input including the ones I didn't intend to remove.
Why is that? I already have a for loop that iterates through each image, why is it clearing the entire input


function previewAdditionalPhotos(event) {
  var previewContainer = document.querySelector('.additional-photos-preview');
  var files = event.target.files;
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var file = files[i];
    if (file.type.match('image.*')) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(e) {
        var image = document.createElement('img');
        image.className = 'preview-image';
        image.src = e.target.result;
        var removeButton = document.createElement('button');
        removeButton.innerHTML = 'Remove';
        removeButton.className = 'btn btn-danger remove-button';
        removeButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
          var previewDiv = this.parentNode;
          var fileInput = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
          fileInput.value = null;
          previewContainer.removeChild(previewDiv);
        });
        var previewDiv = document.createElement('div');
        previewDiv.appendChild(image);
        previewDiv.appendChild(removeButton);
        previewContainer.appendChild(previewDiv);
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
  }
}
<div class="form-group photos-group">
  <label asp-for="MediaFiles" class="control-label"></label>
  <input type="file" name="MediaFiles" multiple class="form-control" onchange="previewAdditionalPhotos(event)" />
  <span asp-validation-for="MediaFiles" class="text-danger"></span>
  <div class="additional-photos-preview"></div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <img src="#">
</div>




https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19060378/how-to-remove-one-specific-selected-file-from-input-file-control

Hi @Wolf，I have shared a simple demo you could test, pls check. If any problems, pls follow up to let me know.

Here is a sample you could follow:
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="uploadForm">
    <input type="file" name="images" id="fileInput" multiple />
    <div id="previewContainer"></div>
    <button type="submit">Upload Images</button>
</form>
@section Scripts {

        <script>
            let previewedFileNames = [];

        function handleFileSelect(event) {
            const previewContainer = document.getElementById('previewContainer');
            previewContainer.innerHTML = '';
            previewedFileNames = [];

            const files = event.target.files;
            for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                const file = files[i];
                if (!file.type.match('image.*')) {
                    continue;
                }

                const reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    const img = new Image();
                    img.src = e.target.result;
                    img.width = 100;
                    img.height = 100;

                    const deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
                    deleteButton.textContent = 'Delete';
                    deleteButton.onclick = function () {
                        previewContainer.removeChild(img);
                        previewContainer.removeChild(deleteButton);
                        const index = previewedFileNames.indexOf(file.name);
                        if (index !== -1) {
                            previewedFileNames.splice(index, 1);
                        }
                    };

                    previewContainer.appendChild(img);
                    previewContainer.appendChild(deleteButton);

                    previewedFileNames.push(file.name);
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            }
        }

        document.getElementById('fileInput').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect);

        document.getElementById('uploadForm').addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the form from submitting normally

            const formData = new FormData();
            const files = document.getElementById('fileInput').files;

            for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                const file = files[i];
                if (previewedFileNames.includes(file.name)) {
                    formData.append('images', file);
                }
            }

            // Example: Send FormData to backend using fetch API
            fetch('/home/create', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData
            })
                .then(response => {
                    if (!response.ok) {
                        throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
                    }
                    return response.text();
                })
                .then(data => {
                    console.log('Upload successful:', data);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error('Error during upload:', error);
                });
        });
    
    </script>
}

Controller
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(List<IFormFile> images)
{
    var files = Request.Form.Files;
    return View();
}

