# How to unselect one file in multiple files selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload, input

I have selected some files in multiple files selection (input type=file) and previewing the images with a remove button.

When clicking the remove button, I need to remove the file from multiple selection.

Is there anyway to do that?

I have tried the code below but the input file unselect all files, and I need to unselect only one

```
var file = document.getElementById("imgsel");
file.value = file.defaultValue;
```

For the following input:

```
<input type="file" id="imgsel" name="files[]" multiple="multiple">
```

Comment: Have you tried use Var file[] =... And console.log to check the content?

Comment: Hi @pecci I have not tried yet, have no idea... can u give me a light?

Comment: Can you make a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net) where we can see / play with the code?

Comment: @KelsonBatista my answer was no good...maybe this answer helps you understand better http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099573/is-it-possible-to-remove-individual-values-from-an-file-input-multiple-element

Comment: Other answers that may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19060378/how-to-remove-one-specific-selected-file-from-input-file-control http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16943605/remove-a-filelist-item-from-a-multiple-inputfile

Comment: Many thanks @pecci I will check and post answer here if I find the solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove one specific selected file from input file control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19060378/how-to-remove-one-specific-selected-file-from-input-file-control)